# Delegates in SWIG - C#

Tags: c#, c++, delegates, swig

( complete duplicate of http://old.nabble.com/C%2B%2B-pointer-to-method-as-parameter-to-C--td17645155.html , but couldn't make the proposed macro work)

I've got the following C++ function (simplified) :

```
InputPort addInputPort(void(*callback)(InputPort));
```

Problem : the signature of the generated C# function is :

```
public InputPort addInputPort(SWIGTYPE_p_f__InputPort____void callback)
```

`SWIGTYPE_p_f__InputPort____void` is not a delegate (and has no public constructor anyway), so I can't use addInputPort.

How do I tell SWIG to use a delegate instead ? If the solution involves %typemap, *please* be extra patient with me...

Comment: I guess C++/CLI is not an option?

Comment: I must investigate further, but I fear it's not : big precompiled pieces of middleware ahead !

Comment: The same issue. Initially I used PInvoke (Details in question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909484/how-to-use-c-sharp-backgroundworker-to-report-progress-in-native-c-code). Now I am trying to use SWIG, but code become very cumbersome... and I also can not realize how to work with delegates.

Comment: @Calvin1602 Have you obtained working code with using info at  http://old.nabble.com/C%2B%2B-pointer-to-method-as-parameter-to-C--td17645155.html ? Thanks. I still can not use C++ function pointer wrappers in C#

Comment: I don't remember, and I don't have the code at hand, but I DO remember that the code at oldnabble really didn't work. Poke me in 3 weeks if you still have the issue...

Answer (score 1):

The solution involves a %typemap. The effect you are seeing is the default useless mapping for unknown types. In your case, the unknown type is the function type `void *(InputPort)`.

In fact, all of SWIG's translation is based on %typemaps which have already been written and live in standard SWIG libraries. You can investigate the initial %typemaps for C# in this [Subversion location](http://swig.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/swig/trunk/Lib/csharp/).

In particular, look for `SWIGStringHelper` in [csharphead.swg](http://swig.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/swig/trunk/Lib/csharp/csharphead.swg). That code maps a delegate to a C callback. The trick is to add a helper callback implementation in the SWIG module.