# Namespace Constants in SWIG

Tags: c#, java, c++, swig

The issue is fairly simple, I have some constants in a C++ namespace that I would like to wrap using SWIG 2.0.8.  It looks something like this:

```
namespace Example {
    static const float PI = 3.14159f
    ...
    /* Lots of classes are here */
}
```

Unfortunately SWIG handles this rather awkwardly.  In the C# case, it adds the constants to a class with the same name as the namespace so it must be accessed by using `Example.Example.PI` even when I am explicitly `using Example` (due to masking by the module name).

In Java, its even worse as it does not treat it as a constant at all and I am forced to call it using `Example.getPI()` as a method call instead of a constant class variable.

If I move the constants to the global namespace, this seems to work but then the variables must be accessed using `ExampleConstants.PI`.

Ideally, I would like both languages to be able to access the constants via `Example.PI` to be consistent with C++.  But a compromise that I would be happy with is if I could have a `Constants` class inside my namespace so that I can use `Constants.PI` in either language.  But of course, C++ does not allow non-integral types to be defined inside a class and this is still not solving the issue in Java.

Is there any elegant way to handle these namespace constants with SWIG?
And if not, is there a way I can manually add a Java or C# class to define them?

Comment: `Example.PI` is not the way to access the variable in C++. You would need `Example::PI`.

Comment: Yes I realize that, but the . is how you use the :: in the other languages.

Comment: Well, you say you want to be consistent with C++ and then you show something that is not legal C++, so your requirements are not very clear.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.  By consistent, I mean as close as possible given the restrictions and syntax of the target languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved similar problem for C++ - C#. I am not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but I hope you will find some info useful for you.

I have not touched Java code in my project.

**Swig solution.**

I created class with public static parameterless functions in C++.

Then I exported them to C# using SWIG.
I specified namespace for C# in command line with `-namespace <name>` key. More details available at page [SWIG and C#](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/CSharp.html)

As a result you can impelement solution to access your constant with `Constants::PI()` and `Constants.PI()`

**Direct solution**

If you would like not to use SWIG or other library, you should use [PInvoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services). There are a lot details and special cases when working with it. Most comprehensive article on subject I have found is [Mono Interop with Native Libraries](http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries)

You should consider [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) for Java.

Note, that C++ functions are exported without namespaces as pure C functions and you should create C# class and create functions with [DllImport attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx) to wrap functions back to namespaces.

In general if your C++ interface is more or less fixed and/or small I would adhere direct solution, because SWIG layer has many-many specific cases which should be learned along with PInvoke/JNI. But if you C++ interface frequently changed and requires a lot of effort to keep C++, C# and Java consistent, you defenitely need to consider SWIG.

You may find non-trivial example using PInvoke at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11909571/13441

**Concerning C++ constants**. You can specify C++ constant inside class, refer to [C++ static constant string (class member)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563897/c-static-constant-string-class-member) for details.

I use SWIG 1.3.40.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks!  The PInvoke idea sounds like it might work. I will try it out.