# How to change progressBar in WinForms to report progress in native C++ code?

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, visual-c++, interop

I try to use code from [How to use C# BackgroundWorker to report progress in native C++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909484/how-to-use-c-sharp-backgroundworker-to-report-progress-in-native-c-code) for change progressBar in WinForms.
But the function which is called from c++ dll does not started (CSharpReportProgressStatus()), if I create a form. Without creation of the form it works fine.

CppLayer.h:

```
#define DLLAPI __declspec(dllexport)

extern "C" 
{
    typedef void (__stdcall *ReportProgressCallback)(int, char *);
    typedef bool (__stdcall *CancellationPendingCallback)();

    struct DLLAPI WorkProgressInteropNegotiator 
    {
        ReportProgressCallback progressCallback;
        CancellationPendingCallback cancellationPending;
        bool cancel;
    };

    DLLAPI void __stdcall CppLongFunction(WorkProgressInteropNegotiator& negotiator);
}
```

CppLayer.cpp:

```
#include "CppLayer.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h> //Для sleep

typedef void (__stdcall * pfnCallback)(int progress, int* cancel);

extern "C"
{
    DLLAPI void __stdcall CppLongFunction(WorkProgressInteropNegotiator& negotiator)
    {
        const int STEP_COUNT = 12;

        char * messages[3] = {"ONE", "TWO", "THREE"};

        for (int i = 0; i < STEP_COUNT; i++)
        {
            Sleep(100);

            if (negotiator.cancellationPending()) {
                negotiator.cancel = true; 
                break;
            }

            std::cout << "Calculate " << i << std::endl;
            negotiator.progressCallback((i + 1) * 100 / STEP_COUNT, messages[i % 3]);
        }
    }
};
```

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CallBackFromCpp
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Presenter p = new Presenter();
            Application.Run(p.Init());
        }
    }
}
```

Form1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CallBackFromCpp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public event EventHandler StartEvent;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (StartEvent != null)
                StartEvent(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Presenter.cs:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CallBackFromCpp
{
    public class Presenter
    {
        Form1 _view;

        public ApplicationContext Init()
        {
            _view = new Form1();
            _view.StartEvent += _view_StartEvent;

            return new ApplicationContext(_view);
        }

        public delegate void ReportProgressCallback(int percentage, string message);

        public delegate bool CancellationPendingCallback();

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public class WorkProgressInteropNegotiator
        {
            public ReportProgressCallback reportProgress;

            public CancellationPendingCallback cancellationPending;

#pragma warning disable 0649
            // C# does not see this member is set up in native code, we disable warning to avoid it.
            public bool cancel;
#pragma warning restore 0649
        }

        [DllImport("CppLayer.dll")]
        public static extern void CppLongFunction([In, Out] WorkProgressInteropNegotiator negotiator);

        static EventWaitHandle resetEvent = null;

        void _view_StartEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
            bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            bw.ProgressChanged += CSharpReportProgressStatus;
            bw.DoWork += CSharpLongFunctionWrapper;
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += CSharpReportComplete;

            resetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

            bw.RunWorkerAsync();

            resetEvent.WaitOne();
        }

        void CSharpLongFunctionWrapper(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;

            WorkProgressInteropNegotiator negotiator = new WorkProgressInteropNegotiator();

            negotiator.reportProgress = new ReportProgressCallback(bw.ReportProgress);
            negotiator.cancellationPending = new CancellationPendingCallback(() => bw.CancellationPending);

            GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(negotiator);

            CppLongFunction(negotiator);

            gch.Free();

            e.Cancel = negotiator.cancel;
        }

        void CSharpReportProgressStatus(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string message = e.UserState as string;
            _view.richTextBox1.Text += String.Format("Report {0:00}% with message '{1}'", e.ProgressPercentage, message);
            _view.progressBar1.PerformStep();

            BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            if (e.ProgressPercentage > 50)
                bw.CancelAsync();
        }

        void CSharpReportComplete(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                _view.richTextBox1.Text = "Long operation canceled!";
            }
            else if (e.Error != null)
            {
                _view.richTextBox1.Text = String.Format("Long operation error: {0}", e.Error.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                _view.richTextBox1.Text += "Long operation complete!";
            }
            resetEvent.Set();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "does not work" is not an appropriate problem description.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved transfer dll call in a separate thread and GUI update via invoke from this thread.

Form1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CallBackFromCpp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public event EventHandler StartEvent;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (StartEvent != null)
                StartEvent(this, e);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (StopEvent != null)
                StopEvent(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Presenter.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CallBackFromCpp
{
    public class Presenter
    {
        Form1 _view;
        WorkerClass _wc;

        public ApplicationContext Init()
        {
            _view = new Form1();
            _view.StartEvent += _view_StartEvent;
            _view.StopEvent += _view_StopEvent;

            return new ApplicationContext(_view);
        }

        void _view_StopEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_wc != null)
                _wc.Stop = true;
        }

        delegate void ShowProgressDelegate(int progressPercentage, string message);

        private void ShowProgress(int progressPercentage, string message)
        {
            _view.richTextBox1.Text += String.Format("Report {0:00}% with message '{1}'\n", progressPercentage, message);
            _view.progressBar1.PerformStep();
        }

        void _view_StartEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ShowProgressDelegate showProgress = new ShowProgressDelegate(ShowProgress);
            _wc = new WorkerClass(_view, showProgress);
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(_wc.RunProcess));
            t.IsBackground = true; //make them a daemon - prevent thread callback issues
            t.Start();
        }
   }
}
```

WorkerClass.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CallBackFromCpp
{
    public class WorkerClass
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Usually a form or a winform control that implements "Invoke/BeginInvode"
        /// </summary>
        ContainerControl _sender = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// The delegate method (callback) on the sender to call
        /// </summary>
        Delegate _senderDelegate = null;

        public delegate void ReportProgressCallback(int percentage, string message);

        public delegate bool CancellationPendingCallback();

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public class WorkProgressInteropNegotiator
        {
            public ReportProgressCallback reportProgress;

            public CancellationPendingCallback cancellationPending;

#pragma warning disable 0649
            // C# does not see this member is set up in native code, we disable warning to avoid it.
            public bool cancel;
#pragma warning restore 0649
        }

        [DllImport("CppLayer.dll")]
        public static extern void CppLongFunction([In, Out] WorkProgressInteropNegotiator negotiator);

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor called by calle using ThreadPool OR ThreadStart
        /// </summary>
        public WorkerClass(ContainerControl sender, Delegate senderDelegate)
        {
            _sender = sender;
            _senderDelegate = senderDelegate;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method for ThreadStart delegate
        /// </summary>
        public void RunProcess()
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true; //make them a daemon

            WorkProgressInteropNegotiator negotiator = new WorkProgressInteropNegotiator();
            negotiator.reportProgress = new ReportProgressCallback(ReportProgress);
            negotiator.cancellationPending = new CancellationPendingCallback(() => { return Stop; });

            // Refer for details to
            // "How to: Marshal Callbacks and Delegates Using C++ Interop" 
            // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367eeye0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx
            GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(negotiator);

            CppLongFunction(negotiator);

            gch.Free();
        }

        private void ReportProgress(int progressPercentage, string message)
        {
            _sender.BeginInvoke(_senderDelegate, new object[] { progressPercentage, message });
        }

        volatile bool _stop = false;
        public bool Stop
        {
            set 
            {
                 _stop = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return _stop;
            }
        }
    }
}
```